# Show/hide fields based on custom object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

what i'm trying to do is to have like one place, object (like in this example `vm.foo`) with `key: value` pairs for showing and hiding my fields. So i could for example just put to my object another pair like: `1502: true` which i could use for example to hide my field with key `1502`

If there is any way to pass my variables from controller for `hideExpression` to use.

Here is just a link to the same small example where item isn't hidden, although `hideExpression` property is set to **true**
http://jsbin.com/rorocitoqi/edit?html,js,output

Below is just a small snippet, it seems `hideExpression` doesn't get my value from `vm.foo[bar]` but when i check `console.log` value is stored in `vm.foo`. If anyone could provide right guideline since i just started with formly, thanks :)

```
vm.foo = {      
  1000: true,
  1021: false,
  3204: true
};

var bar = 1000;

console.log(vm.foo[bar]);
```

---

```
{
  key: 'text',
  type: 'checkbox',
  templateOptions: {
    label: 'Hidden box'
  },
  hideExpression: 'vm.foo[bar]'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how [`hideExpression`s](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/formly-expressions#hideexpression) work. It's a `formlyExpression` similar (not exactly the same) as `expressionProperties`.

Here's [the working example](https://jsbin.com/sinawu/1/edit?html,js,output):

```
{
  key: 'text',
  type: 'checkbox',
  templateOptions: {
    label: 'Hidden box'
  },
  hideExpression: function() { return vm.foo[bar] }
}
```

Comment: Note, for what you're doing, I would recommend you look into utilizing `formState`

Comment: Thank you for quick response and help, also i will try to incorporate and use `formState`